# Calling a module constant error from the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, module

I want to call a constant from one module.

This is the module:
Config/initializers/git_revision.rb

```
module Git
  REVISION = File.exists?(File.join(Rails.root, 'REVISION')) ? File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'REVISION'), 'r') { |f| GIT_REVISION = f.gets.chomp } : nil
end
```

This is how I'm using it now in my view

```
- if Git::REVISION.present?
  %meta{ name: 'version', content: Git::REVISION }
```

But throws this error:

```
uninitialized constant Git::REVISION
```

Comment: where is the `Git` module file localed?

Comment: the file calls git_revision.rb and it's located in config/initializers. Btw I updated the error output

Comment: have you restarted your server after adding or editing this file?

Comment: if the module is in different file then you also need to use require 'path_to_module'

Comment: @YuryLebedev it was that :D , thank you! I had to restart the server!